# Pandas: imputing descriptive stats using a groupby with a variable

Tags: pandas, transform

I have a data frame like this:

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame({"sex": ["M", "F", "F", "M", "M"], "Class": [1, 2, 2, 1, 1], "Age":[40, 30, 30, 50, NaN]})
```

What I want to do is to impute the missing value for the age based on the sex and class columns.
I have tried doing it with a function, conditional_impute. What the function does is take a data frame and a condition and then use it to impute the age based on the sex and class grouping. Butthe caveat is that the condition can either be a mean or median and if not either of these two, the function has to raise an error.
So I did this:

```
### START FUNCTION
def conditional_impute(input_df, choice='median'):
    my_df = input_df.copy()
    # if choice is not median or mean, raise valueerror
    if choice == "mean" or choice == "median":
        my_df['Age'] = my_df['Age'].fillna(my_df.groupby(["Sex","Pclass"])['Age'].transform(choice))
    else:
        raise ValueError()    
    # round the values in Age colum
    my_df['Age'] = round(my_df['Age'], 1)
    return my_df
### END FUNCTION
```

But I am getting an error when I call it.

```
conditional_impute(train_df, choice='mean')
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong? I really cannot get a handle on this.

Comment: Please also post your expected output.

Comment: Hi, you have two typos in your dataframe (sex instead of Sex, Class instead of Pclass), otherwise, your code runs just fine.

Comment: My lecturer's grading system marked me wrong so I was confused and decided to seek a second opinion. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the right inputs, it outputs just fine...

```
# Fixed input to match function:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sex": ["M", "F", "F", "M", "M"], "Pclass": [1, 2, 2, 1, 1], "Age":[40, 30, 30, 50, np.nan]})

def conditional_impute(input_df, choice='median'):
    my_df = input_df.copy()
    # if choice is not median or mean, raise valueerror
    if choice == "mean" or choice == "median":
        my_df['Age'] = my_df['Age'].fillna(my_df.groupby(["Sex","Pclass"])['Age'].transform(choice))
    else:
        raise ValueError()    
    # round the values in Age colum
    my_df['Age'] = round(my_df['Age'], 1)
    return my_df

conditional_impute(df, choice='mean')
```

Output:

```
  Sex  Pclass   Age
0   M       1  40.0
1   F       2  30.0
2   F       2  30.0
3   M       1  50.0
4   M       1  45.0
```